# Dialogflow Integrations (Using the fulfillment webhook model versus API interactions model)

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to understand the different model in building a bot using dialogflow and came across this 2 methods.

1. Fulfillment model (with webhook enabled) [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) [image]
2. API Interactions [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/api-overview) [image]

I understand that both of this models have their own pros and cons, and I understand how they both work. Most online examples are showing the fulfillment method (I guess that's more common?)

However, I would still like to ask what reason will it be to choose one or the other? If anyone had used either model before, what limitations are there?

p/s: I've look through quite a number of tutorials, and read through the dialogflow documentation.

Answer (score 1):

the integration by fulfillment is indeed the default approach because you use DialogFlow to design your conversation flow and (big bonus) manage the integration with the various channels (ie Telegram, Facebook). 
It is the easiest way to design a fully fledge conversation, you only need to worry about the post hooks that are sent to your backend to either save the data or alter the conversation (add contexts or trigger events).

**Important remark**: all user traffic (who says what) goes via Dialogflow cloud

The API interaction becomes a good option when you have already an existing frontend (say an existing application or web sites) and you want to plug in DialogFlow NLP capabilities.
I have done something like that to create a FAQ chatbot that called DialogFlow to identify which intent would match a certain phrase while the BOT was deployed in MS Teams.
The architecture would indeed look like the one in the documentation: MS Team ecosystem is the "End-User" part, then my Java app ("Your System") would use the API to call DialogFlow.

**Important remark**: only given statements (the ones you send) go to Dialogflow cloud